# CURSOR going into infinite loop

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
DECLARE  AssigChart CURSOR FOR SELECT  vad_id_no, drv_id_no, vad_st_dt, vad_st_tm, vad_fn_dt, vad_fn_tm FROM lu02vad WHERE lTachoSmartCardID = @tachoSmartCardID

    OPEN AssigChart FETCH NEXT FROM AssigChart INTO @ChartID, @drvid, @dStartTime, @lStartTime, @dEndTime, @lEndTime
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
    BEGIN


<------------------some processing ---------------------->>>>>>>>


FETCH NEXT FROM AssigChart 
         INTO @ChartID, @drvid, @dStartTime, @lStartTime, @dEndTime, @lEndTime
    END
    CLOSE AssigChart
    DEALLOCATE AssigChart
```

Comment: Does `some processing` contain any other cursor code? I've seen people screw up nested cursors plenty of times. Also, the usual use of `@@FETCH_STATUS` is `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0` which checks for success rather than *one* possible failure code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@@FETCH_Status Return following value....

```
0 The FETCH statement was successful.
-1 The FETCH statement failed or the row was beyond the result set.
-2 The row fetched is missing.
```

So for unsuccessfull it can retur -1 and -2 anyone ,soeither you can check it like this....

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
```

or

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS<>-1 and @@FETCH_STATUS<>-2
```

Comment: Not only is the `@@FETCH_STATUS` check incorrect, but you would normally 'seed' the variables with a FETCH _before_ you enter the loop.

Comment: @ElectricLlama i think op fetch it before entring loop...see it..after where op open the cursor...

Comment: we have another cursor inside that processing part , is it resetting @@FETCH_STATUS everytime to 0 ?

Comment: @user2450518 i dont think...when `FETCH NEXT FROM AssigChart 
         INTO @ChartID, @drvid, @dStartTime, @lStartTime, @dEndTime, @lEndTime` run than you @@fetch status set according to that,,,

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE AssigChart CURSOR READ_ONLY LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT vad_id_no, drv_id_no, vad_st_dt, vad_st_tm, vad_fn_dt, vad_fn_tm 
    FROM lu02vad 
    WHERE lTachoSmartCardID = @tachoSmartCardID

OPEN AssigChart 

FETCH NEXT FROM AssigChart INTO           
          @ChartID
        , @drvid
        , @dStartTime
        , @lStartTime
        , @dEndTime
        , @lEndTime

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    -- your statements

    FETCH NEXT FROM AssigChart INTO 
          @ChartID
        , @drvid
        , @dStartTime
        , @lStartTime
        , @dEndTime
        , @lEndTime

END

CLOSE AssigChart
DEALLOCATE AssigChart
```

Comment: If this solution fully suit you, please approve it.

Comment: DECLARE  AssigChart CURSOR  FOR SELECT distinct vad_id_no, drv_id_no, vad_st_dt, vad_st_tm, vad_fn_dt, vad_fn_tm FROM lu02vad WHERE lTachoSmartCardID = @tachoSmartCardID




i have added distinct only and it is not going into infinite loop dont knw why :-)

anyone know abt this ?